# How can I undeploy a heroku app with Django?

Tags: django, heroku

I'm having issues with parts of my website (made with Django) that I create after deploying disappearing because Heroku is very unhelpful with storage.

Is there a way to undeploy and redeploy a site on Heroku? I think this would fix my issue.

Comment: You can delete your app on `Heroku` if you have source code available on `Github`

Answer (score 0):

Heroku runs an ephemeral file system - whilst you can write files to it files are lost when dynos are rebooted (every 24 hours) or when you deploy/restart your application. You need to use other services like S3 to store your files.

**Now comes the redeploy question.**

Since Heroku work on Git-based deployments. So every time you are pushing your new code to Heroku it means that you are redeploying your app.

You can do two things:

1. Delete the old dyno and create a new one
2. Push your new app to the same dyno and remove the build cache.

#### Remove build cache

You can clear the build cache for an app using the following commands:

```sh
heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
heroku builds:cache:purge -a appname
```

The cache will be rebuilt on the next deployment. If you do not have any new code to deploy, you can push an empty commit.

```sh
git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
git push heroku master
```

> Don not forget to change `appname` to your app name.

Comment: I have some files (images) tied to objects that I had in my localhost that were there before I deployed. Those images and objects don't disappear after any amount of time. But when I add a new object with a file (image), the object and image both disappear. Why do the ones made before deployment disappear?

Comment: Also, is there a way to fix this? A way to add objects that don't disappear? Do i need to add the objects in a new app and deploy the new app, or is there a way to add those to an app that already exists.